# Find location of shell / bash function on disk

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-functions

If I have a function like so:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash

    function foo {

    }
```

and the above function is in .bash_profile, or somewhere.

If I use `which foo` it won't give me the location of this command in the shell script.

Is there some way for me to discover where it's located or is `grep` my best bet?

Comment: The shebang (``#!…``) is not part of the function, and including it in the question is misleading, given that the function is probably defined in a file that doesn't use a shebang.

Comment: I am just showing to the reader that it's bash, how is that misleading?

Comment: we have two great answers here, so I think people get it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question was already answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/144772/finding-the-definition-of-a-bash-function/229038#229038). So there are two things that can be derived from this fact:

1. You should do a better research before posting your question here (but well, we all are lazy from time to time)
2. There is a way better trick then `grep` to do what you want

So you can get a source file and a line number of a shell function in your PATH like this: (credit: [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407236/136629))

```
# Turn on extended shell debugging
shopt -s extdebug

# Dump the function's name, line number and fully qualified source file  
declare -F foo

# Turn off extended shell debugging
shopt -u extdebug
```

Comment: Or just use a subshell: `(shopt -s extdebug; declare -F foo)` to avoid having to restore the option state (and assume it was off beforehand).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for the tip! BTW is there a way to make it a script?

Comment: No, unless you source that script, as `declare` would have to be run from the shell invocation where that function is defined. You could make it a... function `find_func() (shopt -s extdebug; declare -F -- "$@")`

Comment: Note that for functions imported from the environment, it would show as `foo 0 environment` so you would not get back to where the function was defined in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

`which` only searches the path. To see what bash really executes use the built-in command `type`:

```
type foo
```

Comment: upvoted, this is nice, but it doesn't give me the file and line number, like `declare -F foo` from the other answer.